# How can I Use Arguments in a Dockerfile with Yarn Workspaces (with CMD)?

Tags: node.js, docker, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying to configure a **Dockerfile** that will:

1. Use arguments in the **CMD** block
2. Work with yarn workspaces for a **monorepo**
3. Use that argument to specify a folder in the **monorepo** to 'start'

Currently, when running the container, it just goes to install dependencies...

The **Dockerfile** is here:

```
FROM node:12
ARG location
ENV monorepoFolder=${location}

WORKDIR /workdir

COPY . .

RUN ls
 
RUN yarn --cwd ${location}

RUN yarn --cwd ${location} build

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD yarn --cwd ${monorepoFolder} start
```

The directory structure is simple:

/ contains all folders/workspaces in the monorepo as well as a package.json

Generally, to start the project locally, I would run:

```
yarn --cwd folder1
yarn --cwd folder1 build
yarn --cwd folder1 start
```

But alas, when I try to run the **dockerfile**, it just tried to reinstall dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out, this works. Cleared my cache/images and it's working as expected!

Any improvements to the Dockerfile and I'm all ears. Will leave this up as there's not a lot out there on this setup.